# sqlalchemy and SQLite shared cache

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

SQLite supports a "shared cache" for `:memory:` databases when they are opened with a special URI (according to [sqlite.org](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html)):

> [T]he same in-memory database can be opened by two or more database
>   connections as follows:
>
> `rc = sqlite3_open("file::memory:?cache=shared",&db);`

I can take advantage of this in Python 3.4 by using the [URI parameter](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect) for `sqlite3.connect()`:

```
sqlite3.connect('file::memory:?cache=shared', uri=True)
```

However, I can't seem to get the same thing working for SQLAlchemy:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:?cache=shared')
engine.connect()
...
TypeError: 'cache' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Is there some way to get SQLAlchemy to make use of the shared cache?

**Edit**:
On Python 3.4, I can use the `creator` argument to `create_engine` to solve the problem, but the problem remains on other Python versions:

```
creator = lambda: sqlite3.connect('file::memory:?cache=shared', uri=True)
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite://', creator=creator)
engine.connect()
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this without backporting the new sqlite3 module functionality to earlier versions.

Answer (score 10):

You should avoid passing `uri=True` on older Python versions and the problem will be fixed:

```
import sqlite3
import sys

import sqlalchemy


DB_URI = 'file::memory:?cache=shared'
PY2 = sys.version_info.major == 2
if PY2:
    params = {}
else:
    params = {'uri': True}

creator = lambda: sqlite3.connect(DB_URI, **params)

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', creator=creator)
engine.connect()
```

Answer (score 8):

SQLAlchemy docs about the SQLite dialect describe the problem and a solution in detail:

> **Threading/Pooling Behavior**
>
> Pysqlite’s default behavior is to prohibit
>   the usage of a single connection in more than one thread. This is
>   originally intended to work with older versions of SQLite that did not
>   support multithreaded operation under various circumstances. In
>   particular, older SQLite versions did not allow a :memory: database to
>   be used in multiple threads under any circumstances.
>
> Pysqlite does include a now-undocumented flag known as
>   `check_same_thread` which will disable this check, however note that
>   pysqlite connections are still not safe to use in concurrently in
>   multiple threads. In particular, any statement execution calls would
>   need to be externally mutexed, as Pysqlite does not provide for
>   thread-safe propagation of error messages among other things. So while
>   even `:memory:` databases can be shared among threads in modern SQLite,
>   Pysqlite doesn’t provide enough thread-safety to make this usage worth
>   it.
>
> SQLAlchemy sets up pooling to work with Pysqlite’s default behavior:
>
> - When a `:memory:` SQLite database is specified, the dialect by default
>     will use `SingletonThreadPool`. This pool maintains a single connection
>     per thread, so that all access to the engine within the current thread
>     use the same `:memory:` database - other threads would access a
>     different `:memory:` database.
> - When a file-based database is specified, the dialect will use `NullPool`
>     as the source of connections. This pool closes and discards
>     connections which are returned to the pool immediately. SQLite
>     file-based connections have extremely low overhead, so pooling is not
>     necessary. The scheme also prevents a connection from being used again
>     in a different thread and works best with SQLite’s coarse-grained file
>     locking.
>
> **Using a Memory Database in Multiple Threads**
>
> To use a `:memory:` database
>   in a multithreaded scenario, the same connection object must be shared
>   among threads, since the database exists only within the scope of that
>   connection. The `StaticPool` implementation will maintain a single
>   connection globally, and the `check_same_thread` flag can be passed to
>   Pysqlite as `False`:
>
> ```
> from sqlalchemy.pool import StaticPool
> engine = create_engine('sqlite://',
>               connect_args={'check_same_thread':False},
>               poolclass=StaticPool)
> ```
>
> Note that using a `:memory:` database in multiple threads requires a recent version of SQLite.

Source: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/sqlite.html#threading-pooling-behavior

Comment: Dear god, the fact that each _thread_ (not _process_) gets its **own** isolated DB (that can't talk to another thread's DB) is subtle. This post saved me days' worth of effort.