# Getting an error during using query.all() method in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I was trying to display all of the entries I've made in my test.db file, but the IDE threw the following error:

```
Usr.query.all()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
**(sqlite3.ProgrammingError) **SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object was created in thread id 16064 and this is thread id 9372.**
[SQL: SELECT usr.id AS usr_id, usr.username AS usr_username, usr.email AS usr_email, usr.profile_img AS usr_profile_img, usr.password AS usr_password 
FROM usr]
[parameters: [{}]]**
```

(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)

Does anyone know what this means?

Following is my app.py source

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Usr(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.VARCHAR, unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(64), unique=True, nullable=False)
    profile_img = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(32), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(40), nullable=False)
    tweets = db.relationship('Tweet', backref='author', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Usr('{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.profile_img}')"

class Tweet(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    title = db.Column(db.Text(64), )
    content = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(280), nullable = False)
    date_modified = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('usr.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Tweet('{self.title}', '{self.date_modified}')"@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', blog_db=blogs, headlines=news)

@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def registration():
    form = Register_Form()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash(f'Welcome {form.username.data}, your account has been created!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('signup.html', title='Sign Up', form=form)

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def usr_login():
    form = Login_Form()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.username.data == 'analfister' and form.password.data == 'sex-t9':
            flash('Successfully logged in', 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
        else:
            flash('You aight man? cause I found zero records of your credentials', 'danger')
    return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=form)

@app.route('/about')
def bleep():
    return render_template('about.html', title='About')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

These are the db queries I inserted directly into the python console with their respective outputs:

```
from app import db
F:\PycharmProjects\BulletinBoard\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py:835: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and '
db.create_all()
from app import Usr, Tweet
user0=Usr(username='test0', email='test0@pychat.app', password='TesT@0')
db.session.add(user0)
user1=Usr(username='test1', email='test1@pychat.app', password='TesT@1')
db.session.add(user1)
db.session.commit()
Usr.query.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\PycharmProjects\BulletinBoard\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1179, in _execute_context
    context = constructor(dialect, self, conn, *args)
  File "F:\PycharmProjects\BulletinBoard\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 688, in _init_compiled
    self.cursor = self.create_cursor()
  File "F:\PycharmProjects\BulletinBoard\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 1042, in create_cursor
    return self._dbapi_connection.cursor()
  File "F:\PycharmProjects\BulletinBoard\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 965, in cursor
    return self.connection.cursor(*args, **kwargs)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object was created in thread id 16064 and this is thread id 9372.
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "F:\PycharmProjects\BulletinBoard\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3178, in all
    return list(self)
  File "F:\PycharmProjects\BulletinBoard\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3334, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "F:\PycharmProjects\BulletinBoard\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3359, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "F:\PycharmProjects\BulletinBoard\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 988, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "F:\PycharmProjects\BulletinBoard\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 287, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "F:\PycharmProjects\BulletinBoard\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1107, in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
  File "F:\PycharmProjects\BulletinBoard\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1182, in _execute_context
    e, util.text_type(statement), parameters, None, None
  File "F:\PycharmProjects\BulletinBoard\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1473, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
  File "F:\PycharmProjects\BulletinBoard\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 398, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "F:\PycharmProjects\BulletinBoard\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 152, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "F:\PycharmProjects\BulletinBoard\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1179, in _execute_context
    context = constructor(dialect, self, conn, *args)
  File "F:\PycharmProjects\BulletinBoard\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 688, in _init_compiled
    self.cursor = self.create_cursor()
  File "F:\PycharmProjects\BulletinBoard\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 1042, in create_cursor
    return self._dbapi_connection.cursor()
  File "F:\PycharmProjects\BulletinBoard\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 965, in cursor
    return self.connection.cursor(*args, **kwargs)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (sqlite3.ProgrammingError) SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object was created in thread id 16064 and this is thread id 9372.
[SQL: SELECT usr.id AS usr_id, usr.username AS usr_username, usr.email AS usr_email, usr.profile_img AS usr_profile_img, usr.password AS usr_password 
FROM usr]
[parameters: [{}]]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

Comment: do you use module `threading` to run it ? Error shows that SQLite can't be used in threads

Comment: nah, I never touched threading

Comment: error shows that it uses threads - object was created in one thread and now it uses in different thread. Better show FULL error message and code which makes this problem. And put these information in question, not in comment.

Comment: I think you're going to need to post more code. As @furas says, the error indicates threading is in use.

Comment: @furas here you go

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48218065/programmingerror-sqlite-objects-created-in-a-thread-can-only-be-used-in-that-sa)