# minimize disk IO with sqlalchemy/sqlite in read-only

Tags: sqlite, caching, sqlalchemy

I am modifying a project that opens a sqlite database through sqlalchemy.

I am running multiple processes of this application, which seems to cause some (locking?) issues. The processes stall waiting for IO (state D in top).

The database is only queried / read, never written to. Unfortunately, the 5GB database file is on a NFS directory, so reading is not instantaneous.

Can I set the database to [read-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910829/sqlalchemy-and-sqlite-shared-cache)? Will sqlite/sqlalchemy then avoid the locking/transaction mechanism? Setting isolation_level="READ UNCOMMITTED" seems not to have been enough. It's not clear to me from the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/sqlite.html#transaction-isolation-level-autocommit) how and whether I should set SERIALIZABLE.

Alternatively, I guess I could [copy the db to memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53253110/885650) first, but it is not clear how to hand the memory database over to sqlalchemy. Should I copy on connect?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by copying the database into memory, by replacing

```
ENGINE = create_engine('sqlite:///' + DATABASE_FILE)
```

with:

```
ENGINE = create_engine('sqlite:///')
import sqlite3
filedb = sqlite3.connect('file:' + DATABASE_FILE + '?mode=ro', uri=True)
print("loading database to memory ...")
filedb.backup(ENGINE.raw_connection().connection)
print("loading database to memory ... done")
filedb.close()
```

followed by

```
BASE = declarative_base()
SESSION = sessionmaker(bind=ENGINE)
```